# Azure Remote Debugging is not working?

Tags: azure, remote-debugging

I followed steps on this link :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff683670.aspx

also try to shut my firewall antivirus off. When I attach to the **WaIISHost. Exe** process visual studio shows my breakpoint as enabled ( I am running only one instance of my cloud service ) but I am not breaking when I should ( I call the WS from console app ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to attach `w3wp.exe` when debugging code inside the website of your web role.

Comment: I hosted a wcf application as cloud service, so i think w3wp.exe is for web application. then also i tried but i didn't find any w3wp.exe.

Comment: If you are hosting your WCF in a worker role, you need to attach `WaWorkerHost.exe`, if it's a web role and you want to debug code in `WebRole.cs`, you need to attach `WaIISHost.exe`, otherwise you need to attach `w3wp.exe`. Are you hosting your WCF in a worker role or a web role? BTW, you need to access your website/web service if your are using IIS to make it start `w3wp.exe`.

Comment: It is WebRole, so it is WaIISHost.exe. i am using a trial account of Azure is that an issue but my trial is not expired still.